# Sql join and remove distinct in two separate column

Tags: postgresql

I have table ordered

```
  form_id | procedure_id 
----------+-------------
  101  |  24
  101  |  23
  101  |  22
  102  |  7
  102  |  6
  102  |  3
  102  |  2
```

And another table have table performed

```
form_id | procedure_id 
----------+-------------
  101  |  42
  101  |  45
  102  |  5
  102  |  3
  102  |  7
  102  |  12
  102  |  13
```

Expected output

```
form_id     o_procedure_id      p_procedure_id
  101           24                     42
  101           23                     45
  101           22                     NULL
  102           7                      7
  102           6                      5 
  102           3                      3 
  102           2                      12
  102           NULL                   13
```

I tried  the below query:

```
with ranked as
(select 
dense_rank() over (partition by po.form_id order by po.procedure_id) rn1,
dense_rank() over (partition by po.form_id order by pp.procedure_id) rn2,
po.form_id, 
po.procedure_id, 
pp.procedure_id
from ordered po, 
performed pp where po.form_id = pp.form_id)
select ranked.* from ranked 
--where rn1=1 or rn2=1
```

The above query return the value with repeat value ordered and procedure ID.
How to get Excepted output?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't quite sure how you would want to handle multiple null values and/or null values on both sides of your tables. My example therefor assumes the first table to be leading and include all entries while the second table might include holes. Query ain't pretty but i suppose it does what you expect it to:

```
select test1_sub.form_id, test1_sub.process_id as pid_1, test2_sub.process_id as pid_2 from (
    select form_id, 
        process_id, 
        rank() over (partition by form_id order by process_id asc nulls last)
    from test1) as test1_sub
    left join (
        select * from (
            select form_id,
            process_id,
            rank() over (partition by form_id order by process_id asc nulls last)
        from test2
        ) as test2_nonexposed
    ) as test2_sub on test1_sub.form_id = test2_sub.form_id and test1_sub.rank = test2_sub.rank;
```

Comment: Please see the below query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64011370/sql-extra-time-calculate-based-on-customer-plan-limit-and-sum-of-plan-used-past